# Find the limit points and exterior points of the following

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $X=\mathbb R$, with the usual metric on $\mathbb R$ and $A=((0,1)\cap \mathbb Q)\cup$ {$2,3$}. Find the limit points of $A$, exterior points of $A$, $A^o$, $\overline A$ and $\partial A$.

Can anyone please explain how to answer this as I don't understand how to go about this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is the union of all rational numbers in $(0,1)$ and isolation points of {$2,3$}. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, any real number in $[0,1]$ is the limit point of $A$. Also note that no isolation point is the limit point. Denote $A^{'}$ as the limit points set of $A$. Then

$A'=[0,1]$

$A^o=\emptyset$  (for $\mathbb{Q}$ has no open set within it)

$\overline{A}=A\cup A'=[0,1]\cup \{2,3\}$  (Closure is the union of limit points set and self.)

$\operatorname{exterior}(A)=(\overline{A})^c=(-\infty,0)\cup (1,2)\cup (2,3)\cup (3,\infty)$  (Exterior set is the complement of closure.)

$\partial A=\overline{A}\cap\overline{A^c}=\overline{A}-A^o=\overline{A}=[0,1]\cup \{2,3\}$  (Boundary is the intersection of closure and complement of closure, or closure exclude interior.)

Comment: What do you mean that no isolation point is the limit point?

Comment: I mean that isolation points of {$2,3$} in this problem are not limit points.

Comment: Why aren't the isolation points limit points?

Comment: Because no point of $A$ is in the (small) neighborhood of {$2,3$} except  {$2,3$} themself ($A\subset (0,1)$).

Answer (score 1):

You need to find those points that are outside of $A$ but still are infinitely close.  By that I mean, there exists an infinite set of points in $A$ that get arbitrarily close to that point. e.g. 0 is a limit point.  This is because $1/2^n$ is in $A$ for all $n$ and they get arbitrarily close.  You could make the same argument regarding irrationals in $[0,1]$ since the rationals are dense in them.